# Convert a recursive list to a data.table R

Tags: r, list, merge, data.table

I have a list of recursive lists which I'd like to merge into a single `data.table`. Each element of the top-level list (`mylist`) has two elements:

1. `Timestamp` which is a character vector
2. `Value` which is a list

Despite the structure (below image), each element appears to have class `data.table`.

The below image shows the structure of this list (code would've been too long):

[image]

```
> str(mylist[[1]])
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Timestamp: chr  "2019-06-01T00:00:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z" ...
 $ Value    :List of 10
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
  ..$ : num 100
```

Right now, I run two loops to get a combined `data.table`:

**Loop 1 to convert `Timestamp` to R date time and set `key`**

```
new_list <- lapply(1:length(mylist), function(n){
  z <- mylist[[n]]
  c1 <- as.POSIXct(z$Timestamp, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', tz = 'UTC')
  c2 <- as.numeric(unlist(z$Value))
  dt <- data.table(c1 = c1, c2 = c2)
  colnames(dt) <- c('time', names(mylist)[n])
  setkey(dt, 'time')
  return((dt))
})
```

The `key` is set for fast merging (open to other faster ways). This loop fails when it encounters an empty `data.table`(4th element in this list).

**Loop 2 to merge list into one `data.table`**

Obviously this works only when Loop 1 does not fail i.e. no null `data.table` in the list.

dt <- new_list[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqJYq.png)]
lapply(2:length(new_list), function(k){
  dt <<- merge(dt, new_list[[k]], by = 'time', all = T)
})

So, my issues are:

1. What to do when one of the entries in `mylist` is an empty `data.table` or `list`.
2. What is the best way to merge them all in terms of speed and possible errors.

The sample data is given below, my actual list has 40 entries, each of which is ~30,000 rows.

**Update: Combined Loop**

```
listMerge <- function(listname){
  ret_list <- lapply(1:length(listname), function(n){
    z <- listname[[n]]
    c1 <- as.POSIXct(z$Timestamp, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', tz = 'UTC')
    c2 <- as.numeric(unlist(z$Value))
    dt <- data.table(c1 = c1, c2 = c2)
    colnames(dt) <- c('time', names(listname)[n])
    setkey(dt, 'time')
    return((dt))
  })

  ndat <- ret_list[[1]]
  lapply(2:length(ret_list), function(k){
    if(nrow(ret_list[[k]]) > 0){
      ndat <<- merge(ndat, h[[k]], by = 'time', all = T)
    }
  })

  return(ndat)
}
```

This works - not sure if there's a faster to get my desired table.

**Data**

```
dput(mylist)
list(A = structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z", 
"2019-06-01T00:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z", 
"2019-06-01T01:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:30:00Z", 
"2019-06-01T01:45:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:15:00Z"
), Value = list(100.050957, 100.080826, 100.120308, 100.053459, 
    100.053825, 100.04792, 100.0679, 100.088554, 100.102737, 
    100.103653)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0a100a6e0>), 
    B = structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:30:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:45:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:15:00Z"
    ), Value = list(38.892395, 45.7738266, 53.21701, 57.08103, 
        62.1048546, 68.58914, 68.98703, 69.5170746, 71.49378, 
        78.59612)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0a100a6e0>), 
    C = structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:30:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:45:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:15:00Z"
    ), Value = list(30.5898361, 29.75237, 27.63596, 26.5089836, 
        25.6826324, 24.909977, 24.4333439, 23.5524445, 23.1864853, 
        22.7402916)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0a100a6e0>), 
    D = NULL, E = structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:30:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:45:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:15:00Z"
    ), Value = list(8.299942, 8.44268, 8.440144, 8.445086, 8.41551, 
        8.424382, 8.438655, 8.46398, 8.445853, 8.476906)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0a100a6e0>), 
    F = structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:30:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:45:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:15:00Z"
    ), Value = list(85.48002, 88.071, 87.71461, 86.2900848, 85.50101, 
        82.4923248, 81.78603, 82.4504547, 82.00605, 82.12493)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0a100a6e0>), 
    G = structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z", "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:15:00Z", "2019-06-01T01:30:00Z", 
    "2019-06-01T01:45:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:00:00Z", "2019-06-01T02:15:00Z"
    ), Value = list(0.870313, 0.862552762, 0.8827777, 0.8639478, 
        0.849139452, 0.874981, 0.833493, 0.89307636, 0.8647241, 
        0.8711139)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe0a100a6e0>))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the 'Value' column `list` to a vector by `unlist` and then `rbindlist` the `list` of `data.table` to a single `data.table`.  Here, we are also assuming that the OP wanted to do some other pre-processing in addition to the `unlist` as showed in the OP's post

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(mylist, function(dat) if(!is.null(dat))
      dat[, Value := unlist(Value)]), idcol = 'grp')
#grp            Timestamp       Value
#1:   A 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z 100.0509570
#2:   A 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z 100.0808260
#3:   A 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z 100.1203080
#4:   A 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z 100.0534590
#5:   A 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z 100.0538250
#6:   A 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z 100.0479200
 #..
```

Also, please note the applying `rbindlist` directly on the `list` with a nested `list` column wouldn't automatically convert that column to `vector` i.e.

```
str(rbindlist(mylist, idcol = TRUE))
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 60 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ .id      : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
# $ Timestamp: chr  "2019-06-01T00:00:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z" #"2019-06-01T00:30:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z" ...
# $ Value    :List of 60
#  ..$ : num 100
#  ..$ : num 100
#  ..$ : num 100
#  ..$ : num 100
#  ..$ : num 100
#  ..$ : num 100
#  ..$ : num 100
# ...
```

So, either we may have to do the `unlist`ing before the `rbindlist` application or after

```
out <- rbindlist(mylist, idcol = 'grp')[, Value := unlist(Value)]
str(out)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 60 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ grp      : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
#$ Timestamp: chr  "2019-06-01T00:00:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:15:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:30:00Z" "2019-06-01T00:45:00Z" ...
#$ Value    : num  100 100 100 100 100 ...
```

To convert the 'Timestamp' to `DateTime`, we can use `as.POSIXct`

```
out[, Timestamp :=  as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ")]
```

#### Update

if we need to do the `merge` by the 'Timestamp', one option is to convert to `xts` and then do the `merge`

```
library(xts)
i1 <- !sapply(mylist, is.null)
mylist1 <- lapply(mylist[i1], function(dat)  dat[, Value := unlist(Value)])
outn <- Reduce(merge, lapply(mylist1, function(x) 
   xts(x$Value, order.by = as.POSIXct(x$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ"))))
colnames(outn) <- paste0("Value", seq_len(ncol(outn)))
outn
#                      Value1   Value2   Value3   Value4   Value5    Value6
#2019-06-01 00:00:00 100.0510 38.89240 30.58984 8.299942 85.48002 0.8703130
#2019-06-01 00:15:00 100.0808 45.77383 29.75237 8.442680 88.07100 0.8625528
#2019-06-01 00:30:00 100.1203 53.21701 27.63596 8.440144 87.71461 0.8827777
#2019-06-01 00:45:00 100.0535 57.08103 26.50898 8.445086 86.29008 0.8639478
#2019-06-01 01:00:00 100.0538 62.10485 25.68263 8.415510 85.50101 0.8491395
#2019-06-01 01:15:00 100.0479 68.58914 24.90998 8.424382 82.49232 0.8749810
#2019-06-01 01:30:00 100.0679 68.98703 24.43334 8.438655 81.78603 0.8334930
#2019-06-01 01:45:00 100.0886 69.51707 23.55244 8.463980 82.45045 0.8930764
#2019-06-01 02:00:00 100.1027 71.49378 23.18649 8.445853 82.00605 0.8647241
#2019-06-01 02:15:00 100.1037 78.59612 22.74029 8.476906 82.12493 0.8711139
```

As it an `xts` object it can be `plot`ted directly to gain more insights about the 'Value' columns

```
plot(outn)
```

[image]

---

Or another option is `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
out1 <- bind_rows(mylist, .id = 'grp')%>% 
           mutate(Value = flatten_dbl(Value), Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp))

str(out1)
#'data.frame':  60 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2019-06-01 00:00:00" "2019-06-01 00:15:00" "2019-06-01 00:30:00" "2019-06-01 00:45:00" ...
# $ Value    : num  100 100 100 100 100 ...
# $ grp      : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
```

Comment: I'm familiar with `rbindlist` but I want to `merge` - the different tables share the same time-stamp but are for different measured parameters. So the final `data.table` would have a single `Timestamp` column and one column per list element.

Comment: @Gautam Here, also there are only two columns and the third is created 'grp'  as an identifier

Comment: @Gautam If you want to merge by `Timestamp` how do you deal with duplicate 'Timestamp' values and also duplicate 'Value's

Comment: The time-stamps in each of the list elements are the same because this is interpolated data from a historian. For any element that's missing some rows, `merge` returns an NA value which is okay for my purposes. The reason I'm keeping away from creating an `Id` column is because this data is fed into another code snippet (not mine) that's plotting/analyzing this data and it's easier to deal with 40 columns there than create 40 subsets based on `Id`. It's a bit complicated but I hope this explains my issue a bit more?

Comment: @Gautam Do you need `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'Timestamp'), mylist)`

Comment: I got an error with that one which I put down to the structure of the `data.table` element but I'n not quite sure. `reduce::purrr` coupled with `dplyr::bind_cols` seemed to work but was slow.

Comment: @Gautam Do you need the 'Value' columns as separate ones while the 'Timestamp' is single column?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to get in an efficient way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out - there's a maintenance shutdown in a few minutes so it might be tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create a single data.table (The term "merge" which is used by the OP is somewhat misleading, here). This can be achieved by simply calling `rbindlist()`. `rbindlist()` takes care of empty elements in `mylist`.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mylist, idcol = TRUE)
```

> ```
>     .id            Timestamp     Value
>  1:   A 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z   100.051
>  2:   A 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z  100.0808
>  3:   A 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z  100.1203
>  4:   A 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z  100.0535
>  5:   A 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z  100.0538
>  6:   A 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z  100.0479
>  7:   A 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z  100.0679
>  8:   A 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z  100.0886
>  9:   A 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z  100.1027
> 10:   A 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z  100.1037
> 11:   B 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z   38.8924
> 12:   B 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z  45.77383
> 13:   B 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z  53.21701
> 14:   B 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z  57.08103
> 15:   B 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z  62.10485
> 16:   B 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z  68.58914
> 17:   B 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z  68.98703
> 18:   B 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z  69.51707
> 19:   B 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z  71.49378
> 20:   B 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z  78.59612
> 21:   C 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z  30.58984
> 22:   C 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z  29.75237
> 23:   C 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z  27.63596
> 24:   C 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z  26.50898
> 25:   C 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z  25.68263
> 26:   C 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z  24.90998
> 27:   C 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z  24.43334
> 28:   C 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z  23.55244
> 29:   C 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z  23.18649
> 30:   C 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z  22.74029
> 31:   E 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z  8.299942
> 32:   E 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z   8.44268
> 33:   E 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z  8.440144
> 34:   E 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z  8.445086
> 35:   E 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z   8.41551
> 36:   E 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z  8.424382
> 37:   E 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z  8.438655
> 38:   E 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z   8.46398
> 39:   E 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z  8.445853
> 40:   E 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z  8.476906
> 41:   F 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z  85.48002
> 42:   F 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z    88.071
> 43:   F 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z  87.71461
> 44:   F 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z  86.29008
> 45:   F 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z  85.50101
> 46:   F 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z  82.49232
> 47:   F 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z  81.78603
> 48:   F 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z  82.45045
> 49:   F 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z  82.00605
> 50:   F 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z  82.12493
> 51:   G 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z  0.870313
> 52:   G 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z 0.8625528
> 53:   G 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z 0.8827777
> 54:   G 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z 0.8639478
> 55:   G 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z 0.8491395
> 56:   G 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z  0.874981
> 57:   G 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z  0.833493
> 58:   G 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z 0.8930764
> 59:   G 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z 0.8647241
> 60:   G 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z 0.8711139
>     .id            Timestamp     Value
> ```

In a subsequent step, `Timestamp` can be coerced to `POSIXct` in one go (instead of manipulating the single elements of `mylist` beforehand):

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mylist, idcol = TRUE)[
  , Timestamp := lubridate::as_datetime(Timestamp)][]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `rbindlist` and `dcast`. Since this is similar to @Uwe and @akrun, I will also do [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr).

```
library(data.table)
bind_list = rbindlist(mylist, idcol = "ID")
dcast(bind_list, Timestamp ~ ID)

               Timestamp        A        B        C        E        F         G
 1: 2019-06-01T00:00:00Z  100.051  38.8924 30.58984 8.299942 85.48002  0.870313
 2: 2019-06-01T00:15:00Z 100.0808 45.77383 29.75237  8.44268   88.071 0.8625528
 3: 2019-06-01T00:30:00Z 100.1203 53.21701 27.63596 8.440144 87.71461 0.8827777
 4: 2019-06-01T00:45:00Z 100.0535 57.08103 26.50898 8.445086 86.29008 0.8639478
 5: 2019-06-01T01:00:00Z 100.0538 62.10485 25.68263  8.41551 85.50101 0.8491395
 6: 2019-06-01T01:15:00Z 100.0479 68.58914 24.90998 8.424382 82.49232  0.874981
 7: 2019-06-01T01:30:00Z 100.0679 68.98703 24.43334 8.438655 81.78603  0.833493
 8: 2019-06-01T01:45:00Z 100.0886 69.51707 23.55244  8.46398 82.45045 0.8930764
 9: 2019-06-01T02:00:00Z 100.1027 71.49378 23.18649 8.445853 82.00605 0.8647241
10: 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z 100.1037 78.59612 22.74029 8.476906 82.12493 0.8711139
```

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
bind_list = bind_rows(mylist, .id = "ID")
pivot_wider(bind_list, id_cols = Timestamp, values_from = Value, names_from = ID)

              Timestamp        A        B        C        E        F         G
1  2019-06-01T00:00:00Z  100.051  38.8924 30.58984 8.299942 85.48002  0.870313
2  2019-06-01T00:15:00Z 100.0808 45.77383 29.75237  8.44268   88.071 0.8625528
3  2019-06-01T00:30:00Z 100.1203 53.21701 27.63596 8.440144 87.71461 0.8827777
4  2019-06-01T00:45:00Z 100.0535 57.08103 26.50898 8.445086 86.29008 0.8639478
5  2019-06-01T01:00:00Z 100.0538 62.10485 25.68263  8.41551 85.50101 0.8491395
6  2019-06-01T01:15:00Z 100.0479 68.58914 24.90998 8.424382 82.49232  0.874981
7  2019-06-01T01:30:00Z 100.0679 68.98703 24.43334 8.438655 81.78603  0.833493
8  2019-06-01T01:45:00Z 100.0886 69.51707 23.55244  8.46398 82.45045 0.8930764
9  2019-06-01T02:00:00Z 100.1027 71.49378 23.18649 8.445853 82.00605 0.8647241
10 2019-06-01T02:15:00Z 100.1037 78.59612 22.74029 8.476906 82.12493 0.8711139
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous: the question refers to a recursive need, but the data provided are not. If the data are different levels of lists of data.tables, the following recursive function works :

```
rbindlistRecursive <- function(ll) {
  if (is(ll, "list")) {
    ll <- lapply(ll, rbindlistRecursive)
    ll <- rbindlist(ll, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE, idcol = FALSE)
  }
  ll
}
rbindlistRecursive(myList) # works whether recursive or not
```

The `idcol` argument can be modified, of course.